# My collapsing toolbar is not collapsing

Tags: android-coordinatorlayout

I can drag the toolbar manually and toolbar and navigation drawer are not working
together, collapsingtoolbar is collapsing a little but its is not merging into appbar. And why are there so many requirements for posting a question here , just adding these lines to meet the error of mostly code in your body

XML containing collapsing toolbar

```js
    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_view" />


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="320dp"
                android:text="What is PMKVY?"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="217dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="400dp"
                android:fontFamily="serif"
                android:text="@string/pmkvy_string"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                android:textColor="?android:attr/statusBarColor"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-1dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="273dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="720dp"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_play_circle"
                android:text="Watch Video"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="141dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="519dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="840dp"
                android:text="How to Enroll?"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="910dp"
                android:fontFamily="serif"
                android:text="@string/enroll_string"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                android:textColor="?android:attr/statusBarColor"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-1dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="565dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button7"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                android:text="Call 1800 102 6000"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1230dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="OR"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button8"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="160dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1170dp"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                android:text="Enroll"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>


    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">



    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">



        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:minHeight="20dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="25dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="30dp"
            app:title="PMKVY">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/toolbarImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:src="@drawable/pmkvy_logo"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="250dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

.java file of xml

```js
package com.example.shrey.myapplication;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class ScrollingActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout drawerlayout1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_activity_scrolling1);

        drawerlayout1 = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout2);

//        set status bar color code
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            Window window = this.getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.material_blue_grey_950));
        }

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar1);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionbar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_navdrawer);
//        <!-- code to change title and its color. -->
        actionbar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ffffff'>PMKVY</font>"));

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view1);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                        // set item as selected to persist highlight
                        menuItem.setChecked(true);
                        // close drawer when item is tapped
                        drawerlayout1.closeDrawers();

                        // Add code here to update the UI based on the item selected
                        // For example, swap UI fragments here

                        return true;
                    }
                });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                drawerlayout1.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    }
```